# Ionic 4 Statusbar fully transparent

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to make my app `statusbar` fully transparent on **android**

using this code on **MainActivity.java**

```
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
       View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
       View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
```

and thin on **app.commponent**

```
this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#11000000');
```

but still not fully transparent

[image]

Comment: Check Edited Answer

Answer (score 0):

**app.component.ts**

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.statusBar.show();
  this.StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
  this.StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#000000');
}
```

Comment: I already defined this in  config.xml , but still the same result

Comment: define like this : - <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="" />

Comment: well, It turns into black !!

Comment: just wondering if your `HexString` accepts alpha channel like so '#000000**00**' ?

Comment: It accepts #11000000 , and it will be the result on the screenshot above, 
but when it be #00000000 it should be completely transparent , but it turns into black